# Java Canvas Graphics not showing

Tags: java, canvas, 3d, jframe

I am trying to make a program that can draw 3D images. I got my program to work when the images were preset in the program, but when I try to add a way for the user to move the object, the image is not show. I have included the main window, canvas and the class that actually draws the objects.

Main Window:

```
package Graphics;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Window extends JFrame
{

    public static JPanel    contentPane;
    public static MyCanvas  c;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    Window frame = new Window();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                    frame.setExtendedState(frame.getExtendedState() | JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                } catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     * 
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public Window() throws Exception {
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        c = new MyCanvas();

        contentPane.add(c);

    }

}
```

MyCanvas:

```
package Graphics;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

import GraphicsEngine.Image3D;
import GraphicsEngine.Point3D;
import GraphicsEngine.PolygonC;
import GraphicsEngine.Transformation3D;

public class MyCanvas extends Canvas
{

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {

        Image3D cube;

        Point3D[] cubeArray = new Point3D[8];
        cubeArray[0] = new Point3D(100, 100, 100);// 0
        cubeArray[1] = new Point3D(100, 100, -100);// 1
        cubeArray[2] = new Point3D(100, -100, 100);// 2
        cubeArray[3] = new Point3D(100, -100, -100);// 3
        cubeArray[4] = new Point3D(-100, 100, 100);// 4
        cubeArray[5] = new Point3D(-100, 100, -100);// 5
        cubeArray[6] = new Point3D(-100, -100, 100);// 6
        cubeArray[7] = new Point3D(-100, -100, -100);// 7

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        ArrayList<Integer>[] al = new ArrayList[6];

        al[0] = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(0, 2, 6, 4));// "Back"
                                                                    // blue
        al[1] = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(0, 1, 5, 4));// "Bottom"
                                                                    // green
        al[2] = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(0, 1, 3, 2));// "RS"
                                                                    // yellow
        al[3] = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 3, 7, 5));// "Front"
                                                                    // Grey
        al[4] = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(2, 3, 7, 6));// "Top"
                                                                    // red
        al[5] = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(4, 5, 7, 6));// "LS"
                                                                    // Pink

        Color[][] c = new Color[6][2];
        c[0][0] = Color.BLUE;
        c[0][1] = Color.BLUE;
        c[1][0] = Color.GREEN;
        c[1][1] = Color.GREEN;
        c[2][0] = Color.YELLOW;
        c[2][1] = Color.YELLOW;
        c[3][0] = Color.GRAY;
        c[3][1] = Color.GRAY;
        c[4][0] = Color.RED;
        c[4][1] = Color.RED;
        c[5][0] = Color.PINK;
        c[5][1] = Color.PINK;

        PolygonC[] poly = new PolygonC[6];
        poly[0] = new PolygonC(al[0], c[0]);
        poly[1] = new PolygonC(al[1], c[1]);
        poly[2] = new PolygonC(al[2], c[2]);
        poly[3] = new PolygonC(al[3], c[3]);
        poly[4] = new PolygonC(al[4], c[4]);
        poly[5] = new PolygonC(al[5], c[5]);

        try
        {

            cube = new Image3D(cubeArray, poly);

            Window.c.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter()
            {
                @Override
                public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        switch (e.getKeyChar())
                        {
                        case 'w':
                            Thread t = new Thread(new change(g, Window.c.getWidth(), Window.c.getHeight(), cube, 10d, 0d, 0d, 0d, 0d, 0d));
                            t.start();
                        case 's':

                        case 'a':

                        case 'd':

                        case 'q':

                        case 'e':

                        }
                    } catch (Exception e1)
                    {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            });

        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
    }
}

class change implements Runnable
{

    Image3D     i;
    int         w;
    int         h;
    Graphics    g;

    public change(Graphics g, int w, int h, Image3D i, double x, double y, double z, double dx, double dy, double dz) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.i = i;
        this.w = w;
        this.h = h;
        this.g = g;

        Double[][] translateArray =
        {
                { 1d, 0d, 0d, dx },
                { 0d, 1d, 0d, dy },
                { 0d, 0d, 1d, dz },
                { 0d, 0d, 0d, 1d } };

        Double[][] yRotateArray =
        {
                { Math.cos(Math.toRadians(y)), 0d, Math.sin(Math.toRadians(y)), 0d },
                { 0d, 1d, 0d, 0d },
                { -Math.sin(Math.toRadians(y)), 0d, Math.cos(Math.toRadians(y)), 0d },
                { 0d, 0d, 0d, 1d } };

        Double[][] xRotateArray =
        {
                { 1d, 0d, 0d, 0d },
                { 0d, Math.cos(Math.toRadians(x)), -Math.sin(Math.toRadians(x)), 0d },
                { 0d, Math.sin(Math.toRadians(x)), Math.cos(Math.toRadians(x)), 0d },
                { 0d, 0d, 0d, 1d } };

        Double[][] zRotateArray =
        {
                { Math.cos(Math.toRadians(z)), Math.sin(Math.toRadians(z)), 0d, 0d },
                { -Math.sin(Math.toRadians(z)), Math.cos(Math.toRadians(z)), 0d, 0d },
                { 0d, 0d, 1d, 0d },
                { 0d, 0d, 0d, 1d } };

        Transformation3D translate = new Transformation3D(translateArray);
        Transformation3D yRotate = new Transformation3D(yRotateArray);
        Transformation3D xRotate = new Transformation3D(xRotateArray);
        Transformation3D zRotate = new Transformation3D(zRotateArray);

        this.i.setTransformation(translate);
        this.i.addTransformation(xRotate);
        this.i.addTransformation(yRotate);
        this.i.addTransformation(zRotate);

        ;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        g.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
        try
        {
            i.draw(g);
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

FlatImage3D:

```
package GraphicsEngine;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class FlatImage3D
{
    public FlatPoint3D[]    p;
    public PolygonC[]       poly;

    public FlatImage3D(FlatPoint3D[] p, PolygonC[] poly) throws Exception {
        this.p = p;
        this.poly = poly;
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) throws Exception
    {
        poly = sort(poly);
        for (int i = 0; i < poly.length; i++)
        {
            int[] xCord = new int[poly[i].al.size()];
            int[] yCord = new int[poly[i].al.size()];
            for (int h = 0; h < poly[i].al.size(); h++)
            {
                xCord[h] = p[poly[i].al.get(h)].x;
                yCord[h] = p[poly[i].al.get(h)].y;
            }
            Polygon p = new Polygon(xCord, yCord, poly[i].al.size());
            g.setColor(poly[i].c[0]);
            g.fillPolygon(p);
            g.setColor(poly[i].c[1]);
            g.drawPolygon(p);
        }
    }

    private PolygonC[] sort(PolygonC[] poly)
    {
        if (poly.length == 1)
        {
            return poly;
        }

        int fs;

        if (poly.length % 2 == 0)
        {
            fs = poly.length / 2;
        } else
        {
            fs = poly.length / 2 + 1;
        }

        PolygonC[] f = Arrays.copyOfRange(poly, 0, fs);
        PolygonC[] s = Arrays.copyOfRange(poly, fs, poly.length);

        f = sort(f);
        s = sort(s);

        int fc = 0;
        int sc = 0;

        PolygonC[] r = new PolygonC[poly.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < poly.length; i++)
        {
            if (fc >= f.length)
            {
                r[i] = s[sc];
                sc++;
            } else if (sc >= s.length)
            {
                r[i] = f[fc];
                fc++;
            } else if (compare(lowestElement(f[fc]), lowestElement(s[sc])) == -1)
            {
                r[i] = f[fc];
                fc++;
            } else
            {
                r[i] = s[sc];
                sc++;
            }
        }
        return r;
    }

    private Integer[] lowestElement(PolygonC pc)
    {
        Integer[] low = new Integer[pc.al.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < pc.al.size(); i++)
        {
            low[i] = p[pc.al.get(i)].z;
        }
        Arrays.sort(low);
        return low;
    }

    private static int compare(Integer[] a, Integer[] b)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++)
        {
            if (i >= a.length)
            {
                return -1;
            } else if (i >= b.length)
            {
                return 1;
            } else if (a[i] < b[i])
            {
                return -1;
            } else if (a[i] > b[i])
            {
                return 1;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Painting is single-threaded.  A Graphics object is only valid for the paint (or paintComponent) method to which it is passed.  You cannot pass a Graphics object to a new Thread and expect it to be usable.  Also note that you are adding an additional KeyListener *every time* you draw your Canvas;  listeners should be set up outside of any painting methods.

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: If you're using `Canvas`, then you should be using a `BufferedStrategy`, there is little benefit in using a `Canvas` otherwise (a `JPanel` is double buffered by default, where as `Canvas` is not)

Comment: Is there any reason you cannot use the new [JavaFX 3D](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/graphics-tutorial/javafx-3d-graphics.htm) features? I think they would be much easier than this.

Comment: This is purely for fun

Answer (score 0):

Your program should be structured as follows:

```
public class MyCanvas extends Canvas {

public MyCanvas() {

  // all the stuff you have inside paint now, except you dont create a new class
// everytime you press a button just create once and direct it by some method

change ch=new change(Window.c.getWidth(), Window.c.getHeight(), cube, 10d, 0d, 0d, 0d, 0d, 0d));

// then 
                    case 'w':
                        ch.adjustParameters(x, y.......)
}

public void paint(Graphics g)
{

  change.draw(g);

}
```

change should be

```
class change {

Image3D     i;
int         w;
int         h;
Graphics    g;

public change(int w, int h, Image3D i, double x, double y, double z, double dx, double dy, double dz) throws Exception {
```

that is not a Runnable.

every time you change something by the key should be conveyed to change (e.g., the coordinates x, y) by some method - but for now you can assume x=y=0 and just make this run.